# Div expands then shrinks - jQuery/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a div that is not displayed at first, but when something is clicked it then becomes visible with a slide down animation.

However, I get that the div that I want to show grows a lot in terms of height then shrinks and im not sure why.

**I find that the problem occurs when the Browser is Refreshed, then a Div is clicked**

**After this it works fine**

**View Code here: http://www.codeply.com/go/EqTMv0dLFP**

Comment: On codeply, it just grows for me -- doesn't grow and shrink. Using OS X and Google Chrome (latest). What browser are you using?

Comment: Can you create a shorter example ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and maybe explain where the problem is?

Comment: @Cymen - Also Using OSX and Google Chrome (latest). Maybe becauase of the scroll animation you may not see it, but it happens ONCE upon refresh

Comment: I couldn't see any new element / sliding animation when I clicked on those links (using latest Firefox on Windows 8.1), so I couldn't see the problem myself. Anyway, have you tried setting `position:relative` to the sliding element? I was faced with similar issue (the animation was not smooth, showed greater height than intended before 'jumping' to actual height) and that solved the problem.